# Dubious math in Thorp's magnum opus

Tags: finance-mathematics, statistical-finance

I started reading Thorp's "Beat the Market" book and stumbled on a formula I can't figure out:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEYfL.jpg

What's the point in adding time to price and the whole probabilites relation after all?

Also what I can't grasp is how does Thorp get the expecation of final gain given the system of inequalities in the lower paragraph of the screenshot.
Thank you in advance!